# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar en segundo plano un script de python3 sin bloquear la terminal ni mostrar la salida?

Tags: bash, script

Buen día, estoy tratando de ejecutar un script `bash` para ejecutar un programa en `Python3`. Al ejecutarlo el script queda a la espera que termine el Python para liberar el terminal y regresa el numero de proceso, por ejemplo "[2] 8544".

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar el script `bash` sin que devuelva nada, como si no hubiera hecho nada, pero internamente ejecute el Python?.

He probado con `nohup` y mandarlo a segundo plano con `&`; igualmente redirigí la salida a un archivo, pero aún así no sale como necesito pues regresa el proceso y "nohup: se descarta la entrada y se redirige la salida de error a la salida estándar".

De antemano muchas gracias!!!

Comment: A quién mandaste a segundo al `bash` o al `Python` que se invoca dentro del script. Debería se a este último.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con:

```
$ nohup <ruta> &> /dev/null &
```

Con bash para que tanto stout como sterr vayan a /dev/null. O en el script de python para que lo haga este.